# Robolectric PowerMock java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error while running a test

Tags: java, android, mockito, powermock, robolectric

I want to integrate powermock to test firebase logic. I tried to run a test and got this:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor`

Here is my app.gradle:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.0"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.7.0"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.7.0"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.7.0"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4.2"
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.1.0'
```

Here is my test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*" })
@PrepareForTest({FirebaseAuth.class, FirebaseDatabase.class})
public class LoginTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FirebaseAuth.class);
        Mockito.when(FirebaseAuth.getInstance()).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(FirebaseAuth.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use the latest version of mockito supported by powermock? For example `testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'`

Comment: Also, wrapping the `final` Firebase classes in your own non-final interfaces is a better solution than using Powermock

Answer (score 2):

You are using `'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.1.0'` with `"org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.7.0"`.

To use PowerMock with Mockito 2 the `"org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0"` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You need the **cglib** library in your class path.

My solution is to always download a "complete" powermock ZIP from [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Downloads). Those ZIP files contain **everything** you need in order to get going with PowerMock.